# Trying to install Wordpress locally by using docker where some folder symlinked to my git directory

Tags: apache-2.2, docker, wordpress, symlink

Using this image with docker-compose.yml: https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress
Everything done by the book and it works till I tried to symlinks some folders to my git repository.

This is the part of my `docker-compose.yml`

```
 wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: wordpressdb
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: cms_local
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
```

Some plugins and themes from folder `wp-content/plugins` and `wp-content/themes` I removed and created symlink instead to my git repository. Unfortunatelly Apache couldn't access them and throw the following error:

```
AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/cms-child-theme, referer: http://localhost/
```

When I tried to `cd` from the docker into these folder I get the following error:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data   80 Sep 19 12:25 cms-child-theme -> /Users/anatoly/Developer/example.com/wordpress/themes/cms-child-theme
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root       28 Jun  5  2014 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 28 root     root      896 Jun 29  2021 twentyfifteen
drwxr-xr-x 42 root     root     1344 Jun 29  2021 twentyfourteen
drwxr-xr-x 34 root     root     1088 Jun 29  2021 twentynineteen
drwxr-xr-x 25 root     root      800 Jun 29  2021 twentysixteen
drwxr-xr-x 23 root     root      736 Jun 29  2021 twentytwenty
drwxr-xr-x 28 root     root      896 Jun 29  2021 twentytwentyone
drwxr-xr-x 12 root     root      384 Feb 28  2022 twentytwentytwo
root@47205851c7e7:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes# cd cms-child-theme
bash: cd: cms-child-theme: No such file or directory
```

Can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symlink is resolved inside the container. You can add the directory as an additional volume

```
volumes:
 - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
 - /Users/anatoly/Developer/example.com/:/Users/anatoly/Developer/example.com/
```

Comment: Thank you, you have saved my day!